# Game Center Authenticate Local Player

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I am trying to authenticate the local player using the following code:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
if(!localPlayer.authenticated) {
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController* controller, NSError *error) {
        if(controller != nil)
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    };
}
```

But the problem is that even though `[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated` is false, the controller that is returned in the `authenticationHandler` block is always nil. Therefore gamer center always seems to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the `authenticateHandler` being set twice. The handler should be set once for the duration of the application's life cycle. Subsequent `authenticateHandler` property being set after the first time will yield unexpected results like the problem I described in the question.

Comment: Please may you post code for the solution. Im having the exact same problem :(

Comment: One down for not posting solution

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Sorry I do not have the code anymore; I think it was removed.

Answer (score 1):

I found this authentication code works fine in iOS 8.

```
- (void)authenticateLocalPlayer
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:LocalPlayerIsAuthenticated object:nil];
        return;
    }

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler  =
^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
        [self setLastError:error];

        if(viewController != nil){
            [self setAuthenticationViewController:viewController];
        } else if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
            NSLog(@"connected to gk");
            _GKConnected = YES;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:LocalPlayerIsAuthenticated object:nil];
        }
        else {
            _GKConnected = NO;
        }
    };

    // REGISTER LISTENER FOR INVITES
    [localPlayer registerListener:self];
}
```

The notification strings can be any constant string (it is good practice to prefix a reverse DNS for use with NotificationCenter `org.myapp.notificationname`).

In the original OP question was an error in retrieving the getter for the `authenticated` property in `GKPlayer` instance: the property name is `authenticated` but the getter has to be `isAuthenticated`.

Can be trivial to catch out those semantic typos, whilst the compiler doesn't warn you because it could be more code behind a simple property accessed with dot notation and by default setters begins with `is`.

By the way I can add a link to a well known tutorial with working sample tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/60998/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-2